# Change the order of a fully qualified string

Tags: php, string, laravel

How can I change a full string name?
I'm using Laravel and would I have to do that using an "**explode**"?
Could you help me in order to achieve the situation below?

Example:

```
Carlos Marinz Dutra
```

For:

```
DUTRA, Carlos Marinz
```

Comment: How do we know which is first name and which is last name?

Comment: What about names like "Joao da Silva"? Should become "da Silva, Joao"?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte  "Joao da Silva" , it would have to be like this: **SILVA, Joao da**

Comment: @ExercitoBR the last string of the original full string name has to be always in uppercase when changed yes?

Comment: @DilhanNakandala, yes, it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explode to transform into array, array_pop to get the last element of the array (an remove in the process), mb_strtoupper to capitalize even special chars like é ã õ á, and implode to glue again with blank space:

```
$name1 = 'Carlos Marinz Dutra';
$name2 = 'Joao da Silva';

$name1 = explode(' ', $name1);
echo mb_strtoupper(array_pop($name1)).', '.implode(' ', $name1);

$name2 = explode(' ', $name2);
echo mb_strtoupper(array_pop($name2)).', '.implode(' ', $name2);
```

Output:

```
DUTRA, Carlos Marinz
SILVA, Joao da
```

Comment: Dutra, Carlos Marinz...ok, but how would I make it stay: DUTRA, Carlos Marinz ... that is, uppercase

Comment: Use strtoupper.

Comment: Or, if you are using special chars like 'João' then use mb_strtoupper

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
$string = 'Carlos Marinz Dutra'; 
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\w+) (\w+)/i'; 
$replacement = strtoupper('$3').', $1 $2'; 
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.

Assuming that you want to remove the last string and bring it to the front in all uppercase followed by a `,` here is another way without using array or regular expression functions.

```
$str = 'Carlos Marinz Dutra';

$lw = strrpos($str, ' ') + 1;
$mod = strrpos($str, ' ');
echo strtoupper(substr($str, $lw)).', '.substr($str, 0, $mod);
```

Output :

```
DUTRA, Carlos Marinz
```